# React router implementation with dynamic content .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

NB: I am new to react router, so maybe my question already exists somewhere.

My web app fetches cards with data about places from an api(title,description,location,etc.) There is a card preview:
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9N6J.png)

After the card is clicked, detailed information is shown:

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZnGy.png)

This is accomplished through Material-UI popup

This elements, however, are generated by a map function

```
{props.searchLoading == 3 || props.searchLoading == 1
      ? props.queryData.map((el) => {
          return (
            <Card
              toast={props.toast}
              key={Math.random()}
              idData={el[0].place_id}
              title={el[0].title}
              description={el[0].description}
              price={el[0].price}
              accessibility={el[0].accessibility}
              category={el[0].category}
              placelocation={el[0].placelocation}
              dangerous={el[0].dangerous}
              likeButtonVisible={verify()}
              reportButtonVisible={true}
              liked={el[0].liked == "true" ? true : false}
              saved={el[0].saved == "true" ? true : false}
              numbersLiked={Number(el[0].likednumber)}
              mainImg={el[0].url}
              images={el}
              saveButtonVisible={verify()}
              adminRights={el[0].username == Username()}
            />
          );
        })
      : ""}
```

I want to add link localhost:3000/place/:id to each individual component. When I run the following code(react-router-dom is setup already)

```
{props.searchLoading == 3 || props.searchLoading == 1
          ? props.queryData.map((el) => {
              return (
                <Route
                  path={"place/" + el[0].place_id}
                  component={
                    <Card
                      toast={props.toast}
                      key={Math.random()}
                      idData={el[0].place_id}
                      title={el[0].title}
                      description={el[0].description}
                      price={el[0].price}
                      accessibility={el[0].accessibility}
                      category={el[0].category}
                      placelocation={el[0].placelocation}
                      dangerous={el[0].dangerous}
                      likeButtonVisible={verify()}
                      reportButtonVisible={true}
                      liked={el[0].liked == "true" ? true : false}
                      saved={el[0].saved == "true" ? true : false}
                      numbersLiked={Number(el[0].likednumber)}
                      mainImg={el[0].url}
                      images={el}
                      saveButtonVisible={verify()}
                      adminRights={el[0].username == Username()}
                    />
                  }
                />
              );
            })
          : ""}
```

nothing is displayed upon data being received. I surmise the reason is because I am not on the actual URL. What I want is when I click the card and the material-ui dialog with more infor opens, react router to automatically change the URL to `http://localhost:3000/place/:id`. This should go both ways, I want to be able to access the place through the address bar. I probably need another component just for that? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome !

Routes must be configured in App.js

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';

// Components, Pages
import Home from './Home';
import Place from './Place';                                // Random name for the example

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" render={props => <Home {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/place/:id" render={props => <Place {...props} />} />          // !!!
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Once this is done, in your example replace `Route` by `Link` (don't forget to `import {Link} from 'react-router-dom`)

**Your card component**

```
{props.searchLoading == 3 || props.searchLoading == 1 ? props.queryData.map((el) => {
  return (
    <Link to=`/place/${el[0].place_id}`>
      <Card
        toast={props.toast}
        key={Math.random()}
        idData={el[0].place_id}
        title={el[0].title}
        description={el[0].description}
        price={el[0].price}
        accessibility={el[0].accessibility}
        ...
      />
    </Link>
   )
})}
```